# How can I load Skype user information into a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, api, textbox, listbox, skype

So I've been working on this program in VB.NET that grabs users Skype information such as handle, birthday, phone number, etc. But I can't find a way to load a specific users information into a ListBox. Here's my code

```
    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    For Each hmm As SKYPE4COMLib.User In Skype.Friends
        ListBox2.Items.Add("<>-----------------------------------------<>")
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.FullName)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Handle)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Sex)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.PhoneHome + hmm.PhoneMobile + hmm.PhoneOffice)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Aliases)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Birthday)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.City)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Country)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.Language)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(("Friends: ") & hmm.NumberOfAuthBuddies)
        ListBox2.Items.Add("<>-----------------------------------------<>")
    Next
End Sub
```

The only problem is, when I click Button8, it loads all of my contacts information into the ListBox, I just want to load the information of the username in my TextBox3.

Here is a visual:
[image]

The TextBox in the picture is TextBox3, the button with the text "Get" is Button8, and the ListBox is ListBox2. How can I get ListBox2 to load the information of the username from TextBox3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this .. but Do not sort ListBox2 !!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim lstHandle as New List(Of String)
Dim lstSex as New List(Of String)
Dim lstPhone as New List(Of String)
Dim lstAlias as New List(Of String)
Dim lstBDay as New List(Of String) '--> you can change to date
Dim lstCity as New List(Of String)
Dim lstCountry as New List(Of String)
Dim lstLang as New List(Of String)
Dim lstFriend as New List(Of String) '--> you can to integer

For Each hmm As SKYPE4COMLib.User In Skype.Friends
    'ListBox2.Items.Add("<>-----------------------------------------<>")
    ListBox2.Items.Add(hmm.FullName)
    lstHandle.Add(hmm.Handle)
    lstSex.Add(hmm.Sex)
    lstPhone.Add(hmm.PhoneHome + hmm.PhoneMobile + hmm.PhoneOffice)
    lstAlias.Add(hmm.Aliases)
    lstBDay.Add(hmm.Birthday)
    lstCity.Add(hmm.City)
    lstCountry.Add(hmm.Country)
    lstLang.Add(hmm.Language)
    lstFriend.Add(("Friends: ") & hmm.NumberOfAuthBuddies)
    'ListBox2.Items.Add("<>-----------------------------------------<>")
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
  Dim x as Integer = ListBox2.FindStringExact(TextBox3.Text)

  If x > -1 then
    Msgbox( _
    ListBox2.Items.item(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstHandle(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstSex(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstPhone(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstAlias(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstBDay(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstCity(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstCountry(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstLang(x) & vbCrLf & _
    lstFriend(x))
  Endif
End Sub
```

Hope this helps and you may improve it !!